# Data is not passing as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props

so as you can see below, when I hover over `data` it shows me the contents of `data` property (for the first two images) but as you see in the last image, I want to pass the `data` as a `props` but it's showing that `data` as an empty object. So why that's happening?

**This is App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Cards,Chart,CountryPicker} from './components';
import styles  from './App.module.css';
import { dataApi } from './api'
import image from './images/image.png'

// console.log(dataApi);

class App extends React.Component{

    state = {
        data : {},
        country: '',
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
        const  dataFromApi = await dataApi();
        this.setState({ data: dataFromApi})
        // console.log(data);
        // console.log('This is componentDidmount sec')
    }
    
    handleCountryChange = async(country) => {
        const  fetchedData = await dataApi(country);
        
        this.setState({data: fetchedData, country: country})
        
    }

render(){

    const {data, country} = this.state

    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>
        <img className={styles.image} src={image} alt="heading"/>
        <Cards data = {data}/>
        <CountryPicker handleCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange}/>
        < Chart data={data} country={country}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

**This Api.js**

```
export const StateData = async(states) =>{
  let stateName = 'Nagaland'
  if(states){
    stateName = states;
    console.log("triggered")
    
  }
  try{
  const response =await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const pop = data.statewise;
  const index = pop.findIndex(st => st.state === stateName)
  const statedta = {
      active :pop[index].active,
      confirmed : pop[index].confirmed,
      deaths : pop[index].deaths,
      recovered: pop[index].recovered
    }
    return statedta
  }catch(error){console.log(error)}

}
```

Comment: Please post your code samples as text, not as images.

Comment: @BrianThompson now check it

Answer (score 1):

The default state value for your `data` field is an empty object.
This could be your IDE is just showing you the default value for that state field.

I would say that it's best to write a `console.log("data:", data)` on line 33,
after you destructure the values. Then induce the handleStateChange() method to execute. If the rest of the code is kosher, then you should see that console.log first show an empty object, and later show the expected data.

Comment: yeah, it showing the data but since I am passing it by `props` when I tried to access in `StateCard` component it's showing empty, can you help me with that?